# Why does Driftnet capture only part of the image?

Tags: man-in-the-middle

I'm simulating Driftnet (using Kali Linux) on VMware Workstation.

I do an ARP poisoning MITM attack first to capture all the packets between two virtual machines (both Windows), then I open Driftnet.

When I capture images sent from one VM to another only part of the image gets captured. I've tried many images of different sizes, it's always the same.

Example: I'm sending this image from one VM to the other[image]

And here is the captured image:

[image]

The image is always cut off at the same place no matter how often I do it.

Comment: just send the image a second time upside down, problem solved!

Comment: sounds like a hardware or memory limitation

Answer (score 1):

I believe Driftnet has implementation limitations which keep it from re-assembling the entire image sequence of packets.  It detects the first packet containing what it recognizes as an image header, but doesn't follow the entire stream of packets to completely capture the image.

There is most likely a fixed-size buffer, or max count of data packets per image.  Is it the same relative percentage of all images, or does a smaller image (smaller in total size then the size of the truncated flower image) pass through completely?

Comment: Yes. I tried much smaller images and it's still the exact same problem. The same percentage of the image gets captured as the flower. So what could be the problem?

Comment: Same percentage of the smaller image sounds like a bug in driftnet, either in the capture code, or the display code.  You may have to go digging in the source.